# Filtering an array in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a search bar in SwiftUI and I want to filter an array as the user writes text on it.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var jobsViewModel = JobsviewModel()
    @State private var isEditing = false
    @Binding var searchText: String
    var body: some View {
       List {
            ForEach(jobsViewModel.jobs.filter {
                searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
            }, id: \.self) {
                JobView(job: $0)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            jobsViewModel.fetchJobs()
        }
   }
```

I tried setting a breakpoint in the line that contains `searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)` but the app never stops there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? It’s pretty easy to *bridge* `UISearchBar(Controller)` to SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @State instead of @Binding for the searchText property and the filtering works as expected.

```
@State private var isEditing = false
@State var searchText: String = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            ...
```

Comment: The list works perfectly and it is visible. It just doesn’t change when the text is changed in the bar

Comment: You are right, that part must have been an issue with my preview. But the view works fine for me by using @State so if that change doesn't work for you then the issue must be related to your view model because I used a hardcoded array instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing @Binding by @State works!